# Codeigniter loading view into colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, colorbox

I am unable to open a href link with the colorbox plugin  when I am trying to call the link from the codeigniter views, the view will not load.  The view loads correctly if I do not use the colorbox plugin.  It also loads correctly if I place the file outside of the codeigniter views folder.

here is an example of the issue im having:

```
<script>
$(".myView").colorbox({width:"700px",height:"575px"});
</script>

<a class="myView" href="myView?uid=$row[user_id]">Load View to colorbox</a>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? And which is the file that is working if it is placed outside the views folder? The colorbox.js?

Comment: Got it working the syntax here is correct. Thanks after checking the console I was able to see that javascript was being included twice which would stop the colorbox from displaying.  When myView.php was in the views folder it was including another instance of the javascript library from a header file that was being included.  Thanks a lot before your comment I was unfamiliar with the console.